# How does this circuit work (digital logic circuit?)

Tags: schematics

I don't really understand how this circuit works.

For example, suppose that Reset (Num 7) is 0, Thresh (Num 8) is 1, and Trig (Num 9) is 1.

After Y1 we get "1", after Y2 "1" too. And logic "1" enters the input Y6.
What comes in the second entrance?

And what comes in Y7?

Please write in detail!

[image: Scheme 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Y6 and Y7 form a **latch**. The current state of the latch circuit may depend on the prior state of the latch. This circuit is well documented so I won't repeat what you can find all over the internet...search for "NAND latch".